Unable to Run my App It keeps Crashing ( android.content.ActivityNotFoundException )
I've been working on an app and when i run the code and try to get into the app it tells me that the app has stopped for some reason ( crashing maybe ) and when i got into the logcat to see the process i found an error ( android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class ) which i don't understand it at all
a picture of it
enter image description here
i was trying to make a introPage that when you click on get started button lead you to the loginPage
Login backend code:
`

package com.example.imtv;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText userEdt,passEdt;
private Button Loginbtn;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    initView();
}

private void initView(){
    userEdt=findViewById(R.id.editTextText);
    passEdt=findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    Loginbtn=findViewById(R.id.Loginbtn);

    Loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (userEdt.getText().toString().isEmpty() || passEdt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please fill your username and password" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (userEdt.getText().toString().equals("test") && passEdt.getText().toString().equals("test")){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Your username or password is not correct" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
`

Login XML code:
   `



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/main_color"
tools:context=".LoginActivity"
                                    

>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"

            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forget your password?"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/Loginbtn"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/orange_button_background"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Don't have an account?"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Register Now"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        "
            />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

Intro Backend Code
 `




package com.example.imtv;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    Button getinBtn=findViewById(R.id.getInbtn);
    getinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(IntroActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}`

Intro XML code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IntroActivity"
android:background="@color/main_color"

                                       >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/intro_pic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="550dp"
                android:src="@drawable/gradient_background"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NO MORE TIME TO WASTE"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="27sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Find the best movie to watch right now"
                android:textColor="@color/Orange"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/getInbtn"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Get Started"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_button_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`


Error log tell you that you don't declare activity in AndroidManifest.

Does this answer your question? Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?

Does this answer your question? android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:

All activities should be declared in the androidmanifest.xml file, from the error message you haven't added the LoginActivity. Check on the android docs on how to declare the activities.
Related question: How to add Activity to manifest.xml in right way?
